# Change two or more spaces to a single semicolon

Tags: linux, string, shell, replace

I am struggling with formatting of a db2 query. I would like to replace 2 or more spaces in a string with a semicolon. I know how to do it with all spaces, the question would be how to change only 2 or more spaces :P

Here is an example, i would like to change this:

```
john doe    1900-01-01    california
```

to

```
john doe;1900-01-01;california
```

The problem is that i have one space in the name field, so i can't use a simple tr command.
In my real job, there can be a single space in any field.

I would appreciate your help very much!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will there always be a date/digit after the name?

Comment: There was a formatting issue, he did put more than 2 spaces in his first example, but the text appearead with only one, that led to the confusion. I fixed it.

Comment: @Andreas: no, this is only an example. There are 7 columns, and the date is before the last column. And i wanted to have something that works for every query. No matter what kind of columns, and data in them. I think i have the solution, thanks to you guys here.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ sed 's/   */;/g' 
john doe   1900-01-01  california 
john doe;1900-01-01;california 
one space  two  spaces   three    spaces
one space;two;spaces;three;spaces
```

Comment: This also works: `sed 's/  \+/;/g'` (two spaces and an escaped plus sign instead of three spaces and an asterisk).

Comment: @Dennis: that is true in most modern sed implementations. Unfortunately, there are still versions in the wild which don't support `\+` so I wasted an octet in the interests of portability.

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
sed -i 's/   */\;/g' your-file
```

This will substitute every 2 or more spaces with a `;` in the file you pass it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to query your database tables with the proper delimiter (ie ";"). See if you can do it that way. Otherwise,

```
$ echo "john doe 1900-01-01 california" | sed 's/ /;/2g'
john doe;1900-01-01;california
```

This will break if the name has 3 or more words.

Comment: `2g` works for GNU `sed`. Other versions may work differently when you use a number and `g` together. Also, there were some missing spaces in the OP's question as it was originally posted. An edit fixed this.